# Best practices (or examples) for testing camera, microphone and speakers?

Tags: audio, video, camera, microphone

I'm trying to understand the best possible ways (technically and from a user experience) point of view to test the user's camera, microphone, and speakers. Or does it really come down to letting the user select an output for each and testing them manually, i.e.:

- I see my self in the camera so it's working
- My mic works b/c there's a visual indicator that tells me it's
  picking up sound
- My speakers work because there's a visual indicator that moves when I
  talk

Thanks!
- Jess

Comment: Look at how skype implemented this. the only valid way to test if the microphone/cam your application is using is to implement some recording and playback functionality. You cannot rely on any applications that come with the OS for testing this because they might choose other default devices than your application does.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your app is network connected, its often the case that people will supply some sort of 'test call' functionality.

This allows your user make a call to a server which can verify that audio and video is received, and send back both audio and video to the user so they can observe that they are reaching them correctly.